# How to make Generic Type as out type if it is reference Type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have one method called

```
T GetService<T>(int serviceId);
```

**I want to know is there any way using which I can call this method without specifying type argument**

I tried

```
T GetService<T>(int serviceId) where T: new();
```

or

```
T GetService<T>(int serviceId) where T: class, new();
```

or

```
T GetService<T>(int serviceId) where T: MyClassName
```

but all the methods failed,

Can any body help me solving this problem,

Few of you might also doubt why I need that,

My actual problem is I have one Method

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassName>> GroupItems(string ItemName)
{
    using(var db = new dbEntities())
    {
       return db.Catagories.Include("Proucts").where(c => c.name == ItemName).ToList().GroupBy(I => I.productId);
    }
 }
```

which gives code analysis warning saying 'Do not nest generic types in member signatures' and I **want to resolve that without changing any thing on caller's side**.
**That's why I thought to make this method as generic and problem I wrote above raised.**

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible. You need to specify `T`. How else would your method know what `T` is supposed to be?

Comment: I thing through output parameter?

Comment: The `T` is basically just a Template which tells the compiler: everywhere this is used, create a "real" method/class with the specific type. If you don't specify the type, what "real" method/class should be created? It's like saying "I want an instance" but not saying of which class.

Comment: Then whats the use of specifying using where T: MyClassName, new()

Comment: @hajirazin: `T` can only be a class with a public, parameterless constructor (the `new()` constraint)  and it must derive from or be `MyClassName`. I suggest you read up on generics, your understanding seems pretty flawed / non-existant.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Can you please suggest any other way change return type of given method above so that Generic inside generic does not get returned, or it is compulsory that I either need to change caller's code or suppress that warning?

Comment: @hajirazin: If you really need this return type, you should simply ignore this warning. The `Enumerable.GroupBy` method has exactly the same return type. Especially in code using LINQ, this warning often needs to be ignored.

Comment: If the method only ever returns `MyClassName`, then why not have it `MyClassName GetService(int serviceId)`? Btw. with "specifying" I did not mean where you define the method, but where you use it. For example if you have a method `T Add<T>(T first, T second)` and use it in one place like `var d = Add(1m, 2m)` and in another with `var i = Add(1, 2)` then two methods will be created. One where `T` is "replaced with" `decimal` and another one where `T` is "replaced with" `int`.

Comment: @Corak But method actually returns IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassName>>

Comment: In your case, If the caller wants the `MyClassName` version of `GetService`, he should do it like `var service = GetService<MyClassName>(serviceId);`. If somewhere else, he wants the `MyOtherClass` version of it, he uses it like `var other = GetService<MyOtherClass>(serviceId);`. - Btw. if you want to return *different* types, based on what `serviceId` is, then using generics is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Okay, so why not have the method be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassName>>GetService(int serviceId)`? If you *know* that there will only be *one* return type, you don't need generics. - Sorry, that's what you have already.

Comment: @Corak all the time my MyClassName will be same, Lets name it as Class1, All the time method will return IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Class1>> 

Problem is I thought to make method generic only because of code analysis warning CA1006. I thought to have return type in T to solve problem. If you have different solution then that will be best help,

Comment: I will ask this question in another thread, Please post your ideas

Comment: Okay, so what @Sheridan mentioned is still relevant. Is this method part of a class with a geneeric parameter? Then his answer with making the method be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, T>>GetService<T>(int serviceId)`. - Maybe it would be helpful, if you provide the class declaration of the class this method is in (just the `public class ...` line) and a minimalistic example of how you instanciate that class and use that method on the instanciated object.

Comment: I use this method in interface which is not Generic type(Repository interface, I use repository pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error with the return type of `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClass>>` in a generic class that has been declared using `<T>`, then I'm guessing that your return type should *actually* be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, T>>`... of course, without seeing your code, this can only be a guess.

Comment: Yes it will work fine if my return type is IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClass>> but and not making my method generic, But this gives code analysis warning saying Don't reveal generic argument in Generic.
So I thought to use generic and make output as generic type

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have more than one question but i'm going to respond to your first one:

> I want to know is there any way using which I can call this method
>   without specifying type argument

Short answer: With your method signature you can't

Explanation : What you seem to want is type inference. With that i presume you want to be able to write:

```
MyServiceType s = GetService(serviceId);
```

instead of:

```
MyServiceType s = GetService<MyServiceType>(int serviceId).
```

Type inference works (simplifying a lot here) right to left. The compiler will not infer T based on the tipe of variable the result is assigned to. Inference for methods works only if T is part of the method arguments and that is not your case (you have only an int).